# Cohomology of $\mathbf{G}_a\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{G}_a$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field.

Is $$H^p(X_{Zar},\mathbf{G}_a\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{G}_a)$$

at all related to $H^p(X_{Zar},\mathbf{G}_a) = H^p(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ via tensor products and direct sums? How to compute it?